# Android: "next" click in a form ends on wrong view

Tags: java, android, focus

I am using following layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:nextFocusRight="@+id/timePicker"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/timePicker" />
 <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/datePicker"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/datePicker"
        android:nextFocusUp="@+id/datePicker" />
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/timePicker"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/button1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am trying to get to the next view with

```
android:nextFocusRight="@+id/timePicker"
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/timePicker"
```

But this doesn't work. When I start in the DatePicker and click next, I get a wrong view, with a normal keyboad layout.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is add the following to all views you want to take focus:

```
android:focusable="true"
```

---

Per [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

> **Focus Handling**
>
> The framework will handle routine focus movement in response to user
>   input. This includes changing the focus as views are removed or
>   hidden, or as new views become available. *Views indicate their
>   willingness to take focus through the [isFocusable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isFocusable%28%29) method*.

---

> **isFocusable()**
>
> Returns whether this View is able to take focus.
>
> **Related XML Attributes**
>   [android:focusable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3afocusable)
>
> **Returns**
>   True if this view can take focus, or false otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you "get a wrong view", which view is getting the focus?

Comment: I get a keyboard with an normal layout to type in some text.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience with Android, getting the wrong view means that the resource values used in compiled .class files are out of sync with the generated R file. Try cleaning your project and rebuilding from scratch.

If this doesn't help, please also post the code for the relevant Activities in your app.

Comment: Didn't help. There doesn't need to be relevant Activity code. You can set a brand new project with an oncreate an setlayout only, and it reproduces the error